# Apply a set of functions to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I'm trying to figure out the best/most efficient way to functionalize dataframe transformations based on some sort of user "config".

The idea behind the config is to have a default set of transformations, then allow the user to customize additional transformations and add them to the dictionary. Then they'd all get applied at "runtime".

I'd like to have some sort of dataframe

```
    'a' 'b'
0    1   2
1    1   0
2    3   1
```

and some sort of dictionary of functions to apply. Ideally, one that accepts both unary and non-unary functions.

A setup that can do both something like

```
df['bool'] = df['a'] > 1
```

and

```
df['sumval'] = df['a'] + df['b']
```

Right now, I have a something like

```
config = {'bool': (lambda x: x['a'] > 1),
          'sumval': (lambda x: x['a'] + x['b']}

for k, f in config.iteritems():
    df[k] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

However, I realize this is pretty horribly inefficient, especially as the number of functions increases. Since apply loops over each row every time, in addition to losing the benefits of broadcast/whatever you call it inherent in things like the boolean statement above.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can track formulas in `config` as a list.  Then you can pass them to the `eval` method separated by `'\n'`.

```
config = ['bool = a > 1', 'sumVal = a + b']

df.eval('\n'.join(config), inplace=False)

   a  b   bool  sumVal
0  1  2  False       3
1  1  0  False       1
2  3  1   True       4
```

You can see that

```
'\n'.join(config)
```

Evaluates to

```
'bool = a > 1\nsumVal = a + b'
```

---

Or similarly with a dictionary

```
config = {'bool': 'a > 1', 'sumVal': 'a + b'}

j, f = '\n'.join, '{} = {}'.format

df.eval(j([f(k, v) for k, v in config.items()]), inplace=False)

   a  b   bool  sumVal
0  1  2  False       3
1  1  0  False       1
2  3  1   True       4
```

In this case

```
j([f(k, v) for k, v in config.items()])
```

Also evaluates to

```
'bool = a > 1\nsumVal = a + b'
```

Comment: Well this would involve rewriting those functions, but still nice +1

Comment: Yes, but you can store the config as strings and that could be helpful

Answer (score 2):

Why not just ditch the `apply` and pass the entire dataframe to the `lambda`?

```
for k, f in config.iteritems():
    df[k] = f(df)

print(df)

   a  b  sumval   bool
0  1  2       3  False
1  1  0       1  False
2  3  1       4   True
```

Let `pandas`' broadcasted operation do the magic.

Comment: How do you have the intuition to realize this? My heuristic is that apply is generally the most efficient -- I read the numpy broadcasting docs, but I'm trying to get a better sense of how power-users like you have this strong model of what is/isn't efficient.

Comment: @SimonRiddell I've learned the hard way that apply is just a fancy wrapper around an ugly for loop with no added performance improvements. You'll come to understand quite soon :) All my initial answers used apply until I learned better ways to do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Does this suggest that clever usage of what you did above is often more general and efficient than resamples or aggregations? I'm thinking of a lot of functions I use in my own code that are artificially constrained (i.e. aggregation requires each column to have its own function, and within the loop only gives exposure to that series, whereas this method could achieve the same with more degrees of freedom).

Comment: @SimonRiddell I can't say for sure because each problem is unique, but as long as you're not using loops, and not using apply unless it's the ONLY way, you're doing it right.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you, fair point to each problem being unique. But this is a useful heuristic. My current heuristic is "If you have nested loops. You are doing it wrong and need applies." I'll update it now to " -- also, try to not use apply too much".

Comment: @SimonRiddell also do note that among the good ways of doing it, some are better than others. Figuring out which is which comes from experience which is something I can't say I have yet :)

Comment: Might only concern with this is you'd be looking at iterating over the DF for each function, however I do like this in case that the functions aren't broadcastable.